# Spark SQL Error while creating a Delta Table with NULL as column in Databricks

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks, delta-lake

I am trying to create a Delta table from `SELECT` statement and a `NULL` value for column. There is no error coming when I create the table but it is throwing a error when trying to run select.

```
%sql
create or replace table test1 as (
  select
    col1,
    null as a,
  from
    table1
);
```

No error coming up.

```
%sql
select * from test1;
```

Error : `IllegalStateException: Couldn't find a#31234 in [col1#31233]`

Answer (score 7):

It is because by writing `null` you created a column of type [VOID](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/data-types/null-type.html) - check your schema.

You need to cast it to a useful type, eg. STRING, when creating table:

```
create or replace table test1 as
  select
    col1,
    cast(null as string) as a,
  from
    table1;
```

Then the query will work.

Comment: why can't a column of type VOID be permissible in a database ? Afterall there is a [VOID data-type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/data-types/null-type)

Comment: Here's a PR that forbids this: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/28833. There's also some discussion around this topic if you're interested.